# Creating Help Function for vb.net desktop Application

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create Help Facility for my desktop application which I developed using VB.Net 2008. I created a form(frmHelp.vb), then I put WebBrowser on this form from toolbox..

I created a word document and saved as a web page with extension file (.html). When FrmHelp_load:

WebBrowser1.Navigate(ApplicationStartup, "\help.htm")

But it gives me an error saying I'm not connected to internet. How can I create help function my application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's `Application.StartUpPath`.
2. you said that you have html file extension but your code is

   ```
   WebBrowser1.Navigate(ApplicationStartup, "\help.htm")
   ```
3. `Did you save your .html file to bin folder?